# Windows Docker Desktop - Kubernetes Dashboard - no data on pods is shown OR access is forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

When running the Kubernetes Dashboard in a Windows Docker Desktop when I click on "pods" either nothing is shown

> There is nothing to display here No resources found.

or I get this error:

> deployments.apps is forbidden: User
> "system:serviceaccount:kubernetes-dashboard:kubernetes-dashboard"
> cannot list resource "deployments" in API group "apps" in the
> namespace "default"

Was there anything running? Yes.

[image]

> **How can I get an overview of my pods?**

What's the config? In the Windows Docker Desktop environment, I stared with a fresh Kubernetes. I removed any old user "./kube/config" file.

To get the Kubernetes dashboard runnig, I did the procedure:

1. Get the dashboard: kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.7.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
2. Because generating tokens via a standard procedure (as found on many places) did not work, I took the alternative short-cut:

kubectl patch deployment kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard --type 'json' -p '[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/args/-", "value": "--enable-skip-login"}]'

3. After typing "kubectl proxy" the result is: Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
4. In a browser I started the dashboard:
   http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#/workloads?namespace=default

After clicking the "Skip" button, the dashboard opened.

Clicking on "Pods" (and nearly all other items) gave this error:

> pods is forbidden: User
> "system:serviceaccount:kubernetes-dashboard:kubernetes-dashboard"
> cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace
> "kubernetes-dashboard"  (could be "default" as well)

It did not matter whether I chose the default namespace.

**ALTERNATIVE:** As an alternative I tried to bind the kubernetes-dashboard ServiceAccount to the cluster-admin ClusterRole.

1. Preparations: create this file:

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: ServiceAccount
> metadata:
>   name: admin-user
>   namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
> ```

```
$ kubectl apply -f s.yml
```

Create this file:

> ```
> apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
> kind: ClusterRoleBinding
> metadata:
>   name: admin-user
> roleRef:
>   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
>   kind: ClusterRole
>   name: cluster-admin
> subjects:
> - kind: ServiceAccount
>   name: admin-user
>   namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
> ```

```
$ kubectl apply -f r.yml
```

Then run this command:

```
$ kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get secret $(kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get sa/admin-user -o jsonpath="{.secrets[0].name}") -o go-template="{{.data.token | base64decode}}"
```

This (or similar alternative) command gives a lot of errors.

Breaking this command down in parts: kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get sa/admin-user ... gives:

[image]

This command: kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get sa/admin-user -o jsonpath="{.secrets[0].name}" gives no result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely a Permissions issue.

Binds the kubernetes-dashboard ServiceAccount to the cluster-admin ClusterRole.

Otherwise it doesn't have the privileges to be able to collect data from the cluster.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: dashboard-admin
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: NAMESPACE-WHERE-DASHBOARD-IS
```

Comment: The example file above was a bit different than other files. This one gives good results!
Thank you very much!

Comment: FYI, the important bit here is: `name: kubernetes-dashboard`. I used `namespace: kubernetes-dashboard`

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, here's what worked:

```bash
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.7.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
kubectl patch deployment kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard --type 'json' -p '[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/args/-", "value": "--enable-skip-login"}]'
kubectl apply -f k8s-dashboard-admin.yaml
kubectl proxy &
```

**k8s-dashboard-admin.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: dashboard-admin-user
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
```

**Open Dashboard** - [K8s default dashboard](http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/) - If you are asked for login press Skip.
`http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/`

Reminder, you can also create other namespaces in k8s:
`kubectl create namespace myspace`